# How to modify Sublime Text 3 color scheme file "filename.tmTheme" to apply background color to all occurrences of a matching text when double click?

Tags: sublimetext3

I think my question itself is quite descriptive and clear to understand what I require.

Actually, I want to apply background color to all occurrences of a matching text when I double click a text or variable.

I surfed entire Internet by Googling tremendously but couldn't find any property that can be used in my case. So that's why I am asking here. My last hope is `STO`.

What needs to be added or modify in my `Sublime Text 3` color scheme file, e. g. `"filename.tmTheme"`?

I am having `ST3 Version 3.2.2, Build 3211`.

In given screenshot, you can see that matching occurrences ($ch in this case) are highlighted with yellow border. I want them to be in yellow background color like `Dreamweaver` does. Any chance?

My current settings in color scheme file:

```
<key>settings</key>
<dict>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#fff</string>
    <key>bracketContentsForeground</key>
    <string>#f00</string>
    <key>bracketContentsOptions</key>
    <string>foreground underline</string>
    <key>bracketsForeground</key>
    <string>#f00</string>
    <key>bracketsOptions</key>
    <string>foreground underline</string>
    <key>caret</key>
    <string>#000</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#000</string>
    <key>gutter</key>
    <string>#f2f2f2</string>
    <key>gutterForeground</key>
    <string>#999</string>
    <key>highlight</key>
    <string>#ff0</string>
    <key>invisibles</key>
    <string>#999</string>
    <key>lineHighlight</key>
    <string>#e8e8ff</string>
    <key>selection</key>
    <string>#0078d7</string>
    <key>selectionBorder</key>
    <string>#0078d7</string>
    <key>selectionBorderWidth</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>selectionCornerStyle</key>
    <string>square</string>
    <key>selectionForeground</key>
    <string>#fff</string>
    <key>tagsForeground</key>
    <string>#f00</string>
    <key>tagsOptions</key>
    <string>foreground underline</string>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: There is currently no way to do this with either `.tmTheme` or the newer and more extensible `.sublime-color-scheme` files.

Comment: Oh dear, I suspected that this might not be the case. That is really shocking to know that why Sublime couldn't have this.

Comment: I suspect it's just because they haven't gotten around to it yet, or no one has suggested it. Search the [feature request](https://forum.sublimetext.com/c/ideas-and-feature-requests) page on the forum and either vote for an existing one or search for a new one. If you then leave a link here I'll vote for it too.